# Better way to change a value and display results?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that displays a number of results based on the value of a select list "#maxrows" (25, 50, 125, 250 results). "#startID" is a hidden input thats value is set to 1 that starts the displayed data from the first one. So each time you click "#next/#prev" it adds or subtracts from its value. Through PHP i display two buttons #previous and #next when the info is returned on the page via AJAX. Is there a better way to step through the results than this?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#processing").hide();

var options = { 
    target: '#return',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#processing').show()
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#processing').hide()
    }
    }; 
   $('#SymbolSearchForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 

function changestart(direction) 
{
var rowsElement  = $("#maxrows");
var rowsValue    = parseInt(rowsElement.val());
var startElement = $("#startID");
var value        = parseInt(startElement.val());
startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ?
value - rowsValue : 1);
}
```

"#processing" is just the loading gif, im more concerned with the "function changestart(direction)" part

Comment: It's kind of an aside, but I assume that your users can also click a standard link rather than pure ajax? It's important in case your users have JS turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with it if it works; don't overcomplicate things that work :). Just be sure you comment your code so you (and anyone else who reads your code) will know what is happening if they look at it.

**Edit**

The reason it isn't working is because you are using the ternary operator incorrectly.

```
startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ? value - rowsValue : 1);
```

is invalid. It should be:

```
startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : value - rowsValue);
```

Comment: @SimpleCoder - i guess your right, if it ain't broke don't fix it. I just would like an alternative. Right now in the PHP script it's using <... onclick=\"changestart('back')\"/ and i dont like onclick and wanted another way

Comment: $("#next").click(function() {
 changestart('forward');
 }); isn't working any ideas?

Comment: it's not doing anything. I would like to include that part as a click function in JS if possible

Here it is in PHP {
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"previous\" name=\"previous\" value=\"Previous\" onclick=\"changestart('back')\"/>";
}

Comment: Sorry, I meant what I was trying as a click function wasn't working. the function itself was, I just want to remove it from the PHP that applies it as a onclick, see my post above your last. Is there a way to remove it from the PHP and add it via JS?

Comment: Yes, use: `$("#previous").click(function(){changestart('back');});` in your `ready` handler, or wherever you want to bind the event.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - thx, fixing the ternary allowed my click functions to work. Awesome!

Comment: @SimpleCoder - for whatever reason, now that this is in a production environment I've had to go back to inline onclick funcitons in the php file. The JS click functions no longer work? Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you are binding the events in the correct place: in the ready event handler, or when you load content via Ajax.

Comment: https://www.kinetick.com/Test/supportTest.php#Symbol-Search it fires the beforesend and complete ajax functions, but doesn't change the results. I don't understand why it worked before, but not now?

Comment: I can't spot problem directly in the source. Could you post the code that handles this?

Comment: Does it have to do with the table being built in PHP and returned to the page? Should I/can I put the click functions in the PHP file?